# How to download a video from url in Swift ?

Tags: swift

I want to download a video from URL temporarily. I mean do not save it to device I just want to shoe it immediately when app is working like "Vine" do

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the **MediaPlayer** framework, with this you can reproduce the video from the url you want :

```
import UIKit
import MediaPlayer

class OnlineVideoViewController: UIViewController {

    var player : MPMoviePlayerController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       //url to see in the video
       var url = NSURL(string: "url_direct to to the video")

       player = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
       player.view.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 300, height: 300)

       self.view.addSubview(player.view)

       //allow fullscreen support
       player.fullscreen = true
       player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.Embedded
    }
}
```

I hope this help you.